# C++ How to detect the Virtual Machine your application is running in has focus

Tags: c++, focus, virtual-machine, detect

I've got 2 applications, each running on their own separate MS Windows 7 virtual-machine (VM). I cannot write software for the host machine as a part of the solution.  I'm coding in C++ with Qt.

This may not be possible, but I want to be able to detect when a VM window has focus (not the application window, but the VM). Both applications are full-screen applications (at least full-screen within the VM) that have application-window focus all the time, but I want to be able to detect which VM the user's keyboard inputs are about to go to before they strike a key.

Any ideas?

Comment: The whole point of virtual machines is that no you can't What could you possibly need this for?

Comment: It may be possible, but it depends on the VM host software. Typically VM's offer at least some way for the guest OS to interact with the host, but the way this is done will different for each VM system. The "vagrant" tool takes advantage of this for configuring guest OS's. As far as I know the host OS initiates communication to the guest, not the other way around - as that could be a security problem.

Comment: There are enough ways. 1. Use sockets to communicate between the applications. It's easy with Qt. 2. If you run both VMs in the same user session, each window has usually enough unique information to detect which one is in the foreground.

Comment: There are various techniques available for code to detect whether it is running inside of a VM or not (the techniques differ for each type of VM, so you have to try them all until one succeeds). However, there is no standard way for code running inside a VM guest to gain access to the actual VM window, let alone query its status (unless the VM provides an API for that purpose). Only the Host OS knows which VM window is in focus, so you usually need code running on the Host (which the OP does not want) that the code inside the VM can communicate with over the VM's host/guest networking.

Comment: I forget to mention that these 2 virtual machines are not networked together (nor are they allowed to be). So using sockets between the two apps is out of the question.

Comment: I want to visually show the user which window is actively taking keyboard inputs. These users are very busy individuals who most of the time must be using their hands to do other things besides using this keyboard/mouse. The purpose of this is just to reduce the chance of mistakenly using the keyboard application shortcuts in one VM which were intended for another. It's more of a convenience thing to cut down on user error.

Comment: It sounds like my only option is to reach out to the vendor who makes the virtual machine software and host machine and ask them if there is an API.

Comment: When you say "which VM the user's keyboard inputs are about to go to before they strike a key." do you mean detecting it from the client they are running? Is this an RDP client? How are they connected to the VMs? Perhaps I'm missing something, but it doesn't sound like your challenge is about detecting if you run on a VM, but rather something else?

Answer (score 7):

There is no 100% way to identify VM or not. But there are some  "indicators":

- specific "devices", drivers, services ( vmmouse.sys, vmci, VBoxService.exe etc.)
- specific registry keys, Windows Product IDs, MAC addresses

All those methods are unreliable but widely used.

VMware provides officially documented ways of VM detection  [is here, (with code snippets)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1009458).
There is a way based on using hypervisor port 0x5658 ("VX") and hypervisor magic DWORD 0x564D5868, which stands for "VMXh"

```
bool IsVMWare()
{
  bool res = true;

  __try
  {
    __asm
    {
      push   edx
      push   ecx
      push   ebx

      mov    eax, 'VMXh'
      mov    ebx, 0 
      mov    ecx, 10 // get VMWare version
      mov    edx, 'VX' // port number

      in     eax, dx // read port
                     // on return EAX returns the VERSION
                     
      cmp    ebx, 'VMXh' // compare with target
      setz   [res] // set return value

      pop    ebx
      pop    ecx
      pop    edx
    }
  }
  __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
  {
    res = false;
  }

  return res;
}
```

Another way - is testing the CPUID hypervisor (HV) presence bit and the name of the HV Vendor:

```
bool IsVM()
{
    int cpuInfo[4] = {};

    //
    // Upon execution, code should check bit 31 of register ECX
    // (the “hypervisor present bit”). If this bit is set, a hypervisor is present.
    // In a non-virtualized environment, the bit will be clear.
    //
    __cpuid(cpuInfo, 1);
    

    if (!(cpuInfo[2] & (1 << 31)))
        return false;
    
    //
    // A hypervisor is running on the machine. Query the vendor id.
    //
    const auto queryVendorIdMagic = 0x40000000;
    __cpuid(cpuInfo, queryVendorIdMagic);

    const int vendorIdLength = 13;
    using VendorIdStr = char[vendorIdLength];

    VendorIdStr hyperVendorId = {};
    
    memcpy(hyperVendorId + 0, &cpuInfo[1], 4);
    memcpy(hyperVendorId + 4, &cpuInfo[2], 4);
    memcpy(hyperVendorId + 8, &cpuInfo[3], 4);
    hyperVendorId[12] = '\0';

    static const VendorIdStr vendors[]{
    "KVMKVMKVM\0\0\0", // KVM 
    "Microsoft Hv",    // Microsoft Hyper-V or Windows Virtual PC */
    "VMwareVMware",    // VMware 
    "XenVMMXenVMM",    // Xen 
    "prl hyperv  ",    // Parallels
    "VBoxVBoxVBox"     // VirtualBox 
    };

    for (const auto& vendor : vendors)
    {
        if (!memcmp(vendor, hyperVendorId, vendorIdLength))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Some of the hardware detection methods implemented relying on the fact how VM emulates CPU behavior. For example, using cache instructions, like *wbinvd* and *invd*, but they are privileged.

Some links to read more:

There is interesting article [about VM & Sandbox detection](https://artemonsecurity.com/vmde.pdf) with some code examples.

I've found a [repository](https://github.com/a0rtega/pafish) with some methods implemented in C. Some of them can be used only on Windows, but there are some cross-platform ones as well

Answer (score 1):

That piece of code should do the work

```
BOOL IsVMRunning()
{
#if _WIN64
    UINT64 time1 = __rdtsc();
    UINT64 time2 = __rdtsc();
    return ((time2 - time1) > 500);
#else
    unsigned int time1 = 0;
    unsigned int time2 = 0;
    __asm
    {
        RDTSC
        MOV time1, EAX
        RDTSC
        MOV time2, EAX
    }
    return ((time2 - time1) > 500);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Why? How it wotks?

Comment: There are differences in the behavior of VMs and a real PC and one way of detecting them is measuring the time it takes between one instruction and another. Please let me know if it works for you. No solution is 100% perfect.

Comment: so what if it's a slower real machine? i don't think it's a good solution